# How to split the matrix based on the column entries in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

I have a *dataset/Matrix* A, with the following features:

```
A = [ 
      2 3 6 2 2;
      5 3 5 6 2;
      4 5 6 5 2;
      6 4 3 2 0;
      2 3 6 2 0;
      5 3 5 6 0;
      4 5 6 5 2;
      6 4 3 2 2;
      2 3 6 2 2;
      5 3 5 6 2
];
```

In the last column, I have entries with 2 and 0. I want to split the `matrix` A into 3 different junks depending on the last column entries 2, 0 and again 2.

Could you please suggest any efficient way to do that??

I would be highly obliged for your earliest response.

Comment: What's the desired result? Cell array of submatrices, right?

Comment: Hi! It's very good you have posted input example, but if you want to be helped you also need to post desired output. This will allow to understand what to you need much more faster without any additional questions

Comment: I apologize for the inconvenience. The desired output would be submatrix_a1 =                                        2     3     6     2     2
     5     3     5     6     2
     4     5     6     5     2

Comment: The desired output would be submatrix_a1 =                                                                                                         
     [2  3  6  2  2;
     5   3  5  6  2;
     4   5  6  5  2]                                                                 
submatrix_a2 =  [ 6  4  3  2  0;
                             2  3  6  2  0;
                             5  3  5  6  0 ]. submatrix_a3 = [      4     5     6     5     2;
     6     4     3     2     2;
     2     3     6     2     2;
     5     3     5     6     2].

Answer (score 3):

I assume the desired result is a cell array of (sub)matrices:

```
B = mat2cell(A, diff([0; find([diff(A(:,end)); 1])]), size(A,2));
```

For your example `A`, this gives

```
>> celldisp(B)
B{1} =
     2     3     6     2     2
     5     3     5     6     2
     4     5     6     5     2
B{2} =
     6     4     3     2     0
     2     3     6     2     0
     5     3     5     6     0
B{3} =
     4     5     6     5     2
     6     4     3     2     2
     2     3     6     2     2
     5     3     5     6     2
```

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you very much for your help! Best Reards

Comment: Moreover, could you please suggest, how can I store cell arrays B{1} and B{3} into a new variable? I am able to do the same using for and if loops; however, to make the code efficient I wish to use only one line.  Thank you again your time and kind consideration.

Comment: @SushilSurwase I'm not sure what you mean. `newar = B([1 3])`?

Comment: @Lusi Mendo. Yes, I wanted a new variable to be newvar = B([1 3]). I would highly appreciate if you could suggest on it. Thank you for your time.